# Can I skip a step in Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a daily task copying data from one spreadsheet and pasting to another.
I created a Macro for this, but I get a new datasheet to copy data from every day with a new date, so when I run my Macro I get the Run-time 9 error.
Easy enough to fix by just changing the date within the VBA but it defeats the purpose of automating a daily task.
Is there anyway of skipping this step or for the script to ignore the error?

```vb
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Fri", _
        "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A2:F6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Calc.xlsx").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("09_01_2022_data.xlsx").Activate  ' Error here
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Calc.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("09_01_2022_data.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: `or for the script to ignore the error` - and do what instead?

Comment: I have some doubts that VBA/Windows accepts such a workbook name: `"09/01/2022_data.xlsx"`. The slash character ("/") should be an illegal character. Does your system accepts it as you show it? If yes, your code should be able to reproduce it for the current day. If the real name would be something like "09_01_2022_data.xlsx" you can use a string variable for the workbook name. `Dim wbName As String` then `wbName = Format(Date, "dd_mm_yyyy") & "_data.xlsx"` and use it as the workbook/window name. But your code is rather primitive, no offence. No any activate, select is necessary...

Comment: I edited the script on here to show date as example, have fixed now. 
I would initially create the macro on the sheet with today's date, but would be looking to use the same script on other sheets that have the same steps and same range cells, but just the spreadsheet is saved with a different date, (example 08_01_2022)

Comment: Then, try follow the suggestion I made above... But, like I said, activating and selecting are useless. They only consume Excel resources and do not bring any benefit. Instead of `Range("A2:F6").Select` `Selection.Copy` you should use `Range("A2:F6").Copy`, for instance...

Comment: @FaneDuru Apologies, I did not see your full comment was hidding behind the ... and no offence taking, i'm pretty new to VBA and this site.
How do I see your full comment  "you should use Range("A2:F6").Copy, for instance...

Comment: I can post an answer showing how to optimize your code, but I need some clarifications: In which sheet/workbook the initial selection does exist? Why `Selection.AutoFilter`? Can't the selected range be somehow set in terms of range address? `UsedRange`, `Range("A1:H" & lastUsedRow) or something similar... I can see three involved workbooks and I need to know the sheets name where the copied ranges to be pasted. It is not good to previously select a range to paste in it. Isn't it possible to know that address range? For instance, the first empty cell in column A:A...

Comment: I see two instances where you have `Selection.Copy` but then don't paste it anywhere -- which I don't understand.  I agree with @FaneDuru that in general you should look to get away from `.Activate`, `.Select`, `.Copy`, and `.PasteSpecial` as you can usually accomplish those tasks more efficiently with a direct assignment and use of object variables (e.g. `rng_calc.Value = myworksheet.Range("A2:A6").value`.  All part of the learning process... (that's the end -- I just used an ellipsis)

Comment: @FaneDuru I copy the data from the workbook (09_01_2022) and paste the into Workbook (Calc)
You can ignore the Autofilter step, this is just a step that makes no difference if it is there or not.
I have not written this code as it is just a recorded macro within the workbook.

Comment: All I am trying to do is run the same code in a different titled worksheet (example 08_01_2022) copying data and pasting in to Calc Workbook, but when I run this code I get Runtime 9 error as its looking for a work booked titled 09_01_2022

Comment: Is the workbook "09_01_2022_data.xlsx" created and saved and open when you do this?  Do you by chance have 2 running instances of Excel going on? Because that sounds like a prime candidate for a problem, depending on what you're doing.  Check you Task Manager when you're getting this error and see if Excel appears 2x as separate line items (both at the top level -- not subs of a single top level Excel). If 2 Excels are running, they cannot see the workbooks in each other's instance (namespace (?) is separate).

Comment: Run Time 9 error is a "subscript out of range" error, which means it doesn't see the filename in `Windows("09_01_2022_data.xlsx").Activate`.  So I think it has to be either the file isn't created yet (saved?) or you have it created in another instance of Excel.  I'll assume it isn't a spelling error or an extra space.  You could check your Project Explorer window in the VBA editor and see if the filename appears there as a project.  If it doesn't, strong evidence you have another instance running.

Comment: Are you copying the new data every day to the same place?  Do you always copy the data to "Calc.xlsx"?

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor yes the data is always copied to the Calc.xlsx, the problem I was facing that when taking data from 09_01_2022_data.xlsx the macro would only work when triggered in that file.
If I tried to run the scrip in another file name (example 10_01_2022_data.xlsx) would fail as the VBA is looking for the file in which was used when creating the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue that I have been facing.

When working across two workbooks, by ending the macro recording on the Copy workbook rather than the one dated 09_01_2022, this has meant that I have been able to run the same macro on other workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

## One possible answer

I think somewhere here I've got a better answer than what is in the comments, plus I can add pictures here.

### Excel Instances

Assuming you're not misspelling the file name, I think it's possible you have are inadvertently running multiple instances of Excel.  You can check this by right-clicking your taskbar and opening up the Task Manager and looking for the appearance of multiple Excels, or you can view this in your VBA editor's Project Explorer.  I've recreated this situation below:

[image]

So what you see above is that there are two workbooks open, plus my VBA editor in the "Microsoft Excel (3)" instance on the Task Manager, and then I forced a second instance and created a workbook "WB_in_another_Excel_instance.xlsx" in the other one.  Note that in the VBA editor, which is part of the 1st instance, you cannot see this other workbook/project in the list.  If you have a similar situation going on, this would be one explanation for your line...

```
Windows("09_01_2022_data.xlsx").Activate  ' Error here
```

...to not work.  VBA code will not see the other instance, and copying, activating that workbook would give you the Run Time 9 error.  Check that.

### Another approach to your code

Not knowing the full extent of your code, I'm taking some license and trying to show you another way of doing some of your code so that you don't need to rely on `.Activate` and step up your VBA skills.

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb_Date_Data As Workbook
Dim wb_Calc As Workbook
Dim rng_filter As Range

Set wb_Calc = ThisWorkbook
Set wb_Date_Data = Workbooks.Add   ' Create new workbook and save it with name later.

Set rng_filter = wb_Calc.Sheets(1).Range("A1:F8")

With rng_filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Fri", _
        "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wb_Date_Data.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
        With .Parent   ' .Parent object is generic, but in this case is referring to the worksheet of the range "rng_filter"
                .ShowAllData
                .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
End With

With wb_Date_Data
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False  ' If you are overwriting an existing file in the next step, this turns off the notification.
        .SaveAs ("B:\OneDrive\Desktop\" & Format(Date, "MM_DD_YYYY") & "_data.xlsx")  ' Save the file with dynamic date name (USA date format)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ' But good practice to turn it back on quickly!
        .Close savechanges:=True
End With

wb_Calc.Activate ' Not necessary, but wanted to show you can use the obj variable _
   ' plus, I sometimes want my macro to end on a specific workbook when working with several.

End Sub
```

The approach above allows the macro to create, name, and save the workbook with the date automatically without you needing to change it.  I am also showing you how to use object variables to assign a range or a workbook (I could have assigned a worksheet, too, but didn't) where you make the assignment in one place one time, and then use the var thereafter.  Then later if you need to change a range or a workbook name, or whatever, you only change it one place.  Just something to consider in your script to make it more efficient.